# limit to display 50 from all the data

Tags: java

hello there i'm a little bit confuse with this code....sorry for my bad grammar..still new in this java.

```
private void loadSessionEvents() {
        ArgumentBuilder arg = new ArgumentBuilder();
        arg.addArg(getSessionLogId());
        DBResult result = DBOperator.getInstance().doOperation(
                FileOperation.class, "loadSessionLogEvents", arg.getTypeInfo());
        // ArrayList<MsmLogIveScreenshots> logEvent =
        // (ArrayList<MsmLogIveScreenshots>) result
        // .getValue("RETURN");
        // setSessionLogEvents(logEvent);

        ArrayList<Object> logList = (ArrayList<Object>) result
                .getValue("RETURN");
        ArrayList<SessionLogEventModel> windowLogs = null;
        if (ValidationUtils.nonNullAndNotEmpty(logList)) {
            windowLogs = new ArrayList<SessionLogEventModel>(); 
            for (int i = 0; i < logList.size(); i++) {
                Object obj = logList.get(i);
                if (obj instanceof MsmLogIveScreenshots) {
                    SessionLogEventModel log = convertSessionLogToModel((MsmLogIveScreenshots) obj);
                    windowLogs.add(log);
                } else if (obj instanceof MsmDbAuditOracle) {
                    SessionLogEventModel log = convertOracleLogToModel((MsmDbAuditOracle) obj);
                    windowLogs.add(log);
                }
            }
            setSessionLogEventModel(windowLogs);
            }
```

i understand that for loop will eventually load all the data..but what i want is it will still load all the data but only choose 50 list of data to show in jsp..sorry again for my grammar..

Comment: iterate loop for only 50 times or else use pagination

Comment: how can i use iterate loop for only 50 ...i trying to using from= 0 to=50 ..and how can i use pagination..can give example or tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common practise here is to take the 50 most recent values. So what I would do is check the length, and use `subList`.

**Example**

```
if(logList.size() > 50)
{
    // you've got more than 50 objects here.
    logList = logList.subList(logList.size() - 50, logList.size());
}
```

If you have less than or equal to 50 elements in your `List`, then there's no need to cut it.

Comment: where do i put the sublist its inside the loop wrapper or??